# Loading a file from an API causing an error because of parsing to JSON

Tags: angular, typescript

I am loading a xlsx file from an API. But loading causes an error because Angular trys to parse the body to JSON.

It is working if I give the request directly the response type like this:

```js
this.http.get(this.url + "/getExcel",{responseType:'blob'});
```

But in my backend I also need an authorization. And if I give the request a HttpHeaders object it isn't working:

```js
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
    responseType:'blob',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': this.authService.getToken()
})
this.http.get(this.url + "/getExcel",{headers});
```

I think the both above should do the same. Shouldn't it?

Comment: you must change the content type to application/x-octet, no json

Comment: `xlsx` files are *text files*. So the `responseType` should just be `"text"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're combining the wrong things. You should do this:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': this.authService.getToken()
})
this.http.get(this.url + "/getExcel",{
    headers,
    responseType: 'blob'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `application/octet-stream` as a `Content-Type`, or not provide Content-Type at all